# syntax error in creating a CLR stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I trying to call my first CLR stored procedure in SQL server 2008. I have successfully compiled the DLL and created the assembly. Now I am trying to [Create the stored procedure that references the registered assembly by using the CREATE PROCEDURE statement.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) Following [this tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/practical-sql-server-2005-clr-assemblies/), I am getting the syntax error...

```
--This line worked. Just including this code just to show what I am doing ...
--create assembly 
--LevenshteinLibrary
--from 'Drive Letter:\Path\LevenshteinLibrary.dll'

create procedure testCLR(@s1 nvarchar(1000), @s2 nvarchar(1000))
as external LevenshteinLibrary.getLevenshteinDistance  --Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

What should I do to create this procedure? I don't see anything on the msdn [create procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) page explaining the proper syntax for "as external."

The VB.net code looks like this:

```
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server

Partial Public Class LevenshteinerAndSoundexer

<SqlProcedure()> _
Public Shared Function getLevenshteinDistance(ByVal string1 As String, ByVal String2 As String) As Integer
```

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for SQL 2000, which didn't have CLR procedures. The [2008 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926(v=sql.100).aspx) shows the correct syntax (which is not what you have right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
create procedure testCLR(@s1 nvarchar(1000), @s2 nvarchar(1000))
as external NAME LevenshteinLibrary.LevenshteinerAndSoundexer.getLevenshteinDistance
```

The doc for `As External` has a three part name, and you only had two parts.

Also, as Pondlife points out, `As External` needs `NAME` after it too.

---

Usually, the Class is a "Partial" class, I'm not sure how yours ended up as not one.  I think that you may also need to prefix your VB method with an attribute, like this:

```
Partial Public Class LevenshteinerAndSoundexer

    <SqlProcedure()> _
    Public Shared Function getLevenshteinDistance(ByVal string1 As String, ByVal String2 As String) As Integer
```

---

You might want to look at this article and follow the process that they describe there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You also need to have `AS EXTERNAL NAME`; omitting `NAME` will give a syntax error.

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks. it returns an error 
Could not find Type 'LevenshteinerAndSoundexer' in assembly 'LevenshteinLibrary'.

Comment: @Pondlife This doesn't work in SQL Server 2019; if you have square brackets around the name, you get this error; if you don't you get an error stating "CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement in the batch" even though it is and another about the third `.` in the CLR namespace being "Incorrect syntax".

Comment: @Pondlife Correction to my previous comment; I was wrapping square brackets around the entire external name reference; it seems the `.` has a special meaning for the external name and thus it requires there to only be 2 in the form: `MyDatabaseAssemblyReference.[MyNamespace.MyClass].MyMethod`.  I am still trying to figure this out however as I'm now being told my return types do not match between the C# method and Scalar Function I'm trying to create for it.